# Properties that remain invariant under deformation retraction map

Tags: algebraic-topology

I am studying Algebraic topology where I came across the kind of maps called retraction, specifically deformation retraction. What kind of properties are conserved under such maps?

From what I could see, compactness is preserved and connectedness seems to be another such property. What else could we say about the properties of the image (the space to which the original has been retracted to) inherited from the original space?

Comment: Homotopy type...In algebraic topology  point of view, this is one of the most important property

Comment: @Anubhav.K this invariance is why deformation retraction maps are studied, correct? I haven't studied algebraic topology in 2+ years.

Comment: In fact if $X$ and $Y$ are homotopy equivalent, there is a third space $Z$ which deformation retracts to both.

Comment: @GrumpyP Assuming they're both CW complexes, of course, since I think you'd like to invoke Whitehead. One of my favorite invocations of that result is that the solid torus deformation retracts onto any (smooth) knot inside it that winds around the trefoil once.

Comment: @MikeMiller: it's true for arbitrary spaces. See Corollay 0.21 of Hatcher.

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip Huh, whoops! Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: All hereditary properties are preserved since the image of a retraction is a subspace of the domain. So Hausdorffness, first-countability, etc. are preserved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, almost any invariant of algebraic topology (since deformation retract is in particular a homotopy-equivalence). This includes for instance homology groups, the fundamental group etc...

(This is why this notion is so useful in algebraic topology)